# Rewrite Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the next stored procedure which inserts values into 2 tables. To the 2nd table I insert id's of 2 last inserts from 1st table

However, I would like to rewrite it with one query instead of using temp table and while.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CurrencyExhange
AS
DECLARE @TmpTable Table
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    BillID int,
    Amount decimal,
    Rate decimal,
    Date date
)

INSERT INTO @TmpTable
SELECT T.[BillID]
      ,[Amount]
      ,CR.Rate
      ,CR.Date
FROM [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].[Transactions] T
JOIN [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].Bills B  ON B.BillID = T.BillID
JOIN [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].Currencies C ON C.CurrencyID=B.CurrencyID
JOIN [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].CurrencyRates CR ON CR.CurrencyRateID=FinanceLabkovich.dbo.GetRate(T.Date)
WHERE LOWER(C.Name)='usd' AND T.Income=1
ORDER BY T.Date

DECLARE @ToBillID int = (SELECT BillID FROM [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].Bills B WHERE B.Name='Purse')
DECLARE @i int = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM @TmpTable)
DECLARE @maxId int = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM @TmpTable)
DECLARE @TransactionID int, @ToTransactionID int, @Amount decimal
DECLARE @date date

WHILE (@i<=@maxId)
BEGIN
    SET @date = (SELECT Date FROM @TmpTable WHERE ID=@i)
    SET @Amount = (SELECT AmountUSD FROM [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].Cashflow WHERE Date=@date)
    IF @Amount > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].[Transactions] (Name,BillID,ToBillID,Amount,Date,Income)
        SELECT "Name"='Currency exhange'
               ,BillID
               ,@ToBillID
               ,@Amount
               ,T.Date
               ,"Income"=0
        FROM @TmpTable T
        WHERE ID=@i
        SET @TransactionID = @@IDENTITY

        INSERT INTO [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].[Transactions] (Name,BillID,ToBillID,Amount,Date,Income)
        SELECT "Name"='Currency exhange'
               ,@ToBillID
               ,BillID
               ,@Amount*Rate AS Total
               ,Date
               ,"Income"=1
        FROM @TmpTable WHERE ID=@i
        SET @ToTransactionID = @@IDENTITY

        INSERT INTO [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].[Transfers]
        SELECT @TransactionID, @ToTransactionID
    END
    SET @i += 1
END
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Clearer problem statement

Comment: Is `BillID` guaranteed unique?

Comment: BillID can be 1,2 or 3

Comment: Are you saying out of all the records in the table, BillID can only possibly have the values 1,2,3

Comment: Yes, BillID can only possibly have the values 1,2,3